# pymssql insert with CP1250

Tags: python, sql-server, encoding, pymssql

in last I ask about read, and I solfe problem when I use CP1250 in charset in connection string:

```
conn_insert = pymssql.connect(host='xxx', user='xxx',
                   password='xxx', database='xxx',charset='CP1250')
```

And it's ok, i see in console polish chars.
But, after insert to database:

```
query = "Update xxx \
            set xxx='"+variable[x]+"',\
            aaa='"+variable[y]+"'\
            where bbb='"+variable[z]+"'"
```

or

```
 query = "insert into xxx(aaa, bbb, ccc) \
            VALUES ('"+variable[a]+"', '"+variable[b]+"', '"+variable[c]+"')"
```

and cursor.execute(above)
there are not polish chars in DB.

What I need to do?

Comment: 1. Pymssql was [discontinued](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668) some time ago; it's not suggested to continue using it anymore. 2. Even though it's discontinued, it supported parametrisation; why are you *injecting* your values? Your code is **dangerous**. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: Why are you hard-coding the codepage *at all*? Python strings are Unicode. Instead of string concatenation use parameterized queries and let the database driver convert between codepages if needed. Although, if codepages matter you should probably use `nvarchar` instead of `varchar` fields to begin with

Comment: Yes, but in table are both, nvarchar and varchar. This it's independent of me

Comment: `nvarchar` strings need to be denoted as such. So if you can't fix this so you're properly parameterizing queries and making them safe, you need to say for example `set xxx = N'"+variable[x]+"'` - that `N` is very important. (But not as important as making your code safe... this is a data breach waiting to happen.)

Comment: Released: Jan 24, 2022 - this is data last version of pymssql, why You say, it's not continued?

Comment: Did you read [the first link](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668)? Just because some random people continue to contribute to it doesn't mean you should keep using it.

Comment: About safe, of course ;) I here not insert data from users, this is app for local use, and this data is safe in start, but it it for test only too, end code will be safer. Now I fight with chars, thaks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Panagiotis Kanavos write above, I don't known, why i use hardcoding cadepage XD I see this in some tutorial, and witout mind ;) do in this way ;)

When I remove this, all it's allright ;) THANKS